# Getting a value from a multidimensional array without accessing it directly

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with various config settings. Here's an example:

$this->data = array();

I want this array to be private so I've created a getter:

```
public function getData(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $x = $this->data;
    foreach($args as $arg) $x = $x[$arg];
    return $x;
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
$value = $obj->getData('country', 'city', 'street');
```

Everything works fine but the problem is that it is 5x slower (tested with 100,000 iterations) than direct access:

```
$value = $obj->data['country']['city']['street'];
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there any way to make this variable read-only or is there a better way to access it without using foreach()?

Comment: I've just tried and now it is even slower (about 9x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create getter with `__get` magic method:

```php
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->$name;
}
```

In such way you can get protected & private properties from anywhere in the same way but set them only inside your class.

If you want only this property to behave in such way, simply use condition:

```php
public function __get($name) {
    return $name === 'data' ? $this->data : null;
}
```

Of course, `__get` is even a bit slower then method getter, but it needs to be called only once for access to `data` property, and every access to any sub-array of it will be as fast as direct access (that means no ugly `foreach` iterations :) ).

Comment: Thanks a lot, RReverser. This is exactly what I've been looking for. It's now about 2x slower than direct access which is great comparing to other methods.